# Getting value from database using id of onListItemClick method

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have a list and the method onListItemClick , and I can get id ,position and the value of the selected item in the list, but I want to get the value of other column named "threadid" stored in database.When the list item is clicked I want to get the value of "threadid" in the row which "id" specifies.Is there a way to get directly the values from database using this onListItemClick? Any suggestions?

```
 @Override
            public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
                  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "posisiton: "+position+" "+"Id: "+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  String str=getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                  Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),Respond.class);
                  in.putExtra("parentmessage", str);
                  in.putExtra("id", id);
                  in.putExtra("position", position);
                    startActivity(in);  
              }
```

Comment: Where do you originally load the data for the list adapter? You should also query the thread id and store it in your adapter. On item click you can get that id for the clicked item.

Comment: yeah am loading in the list adapter, I thought it is not possible because am new with the list view!!!